# why the crud generating bundle is giving error in symfony2.3 framework?

Tags: symfony-2.3

I have upgraded symfony2.2 to 2.3.

After that i was trying to generate crud for entity class using console command "generate:doctrine:crud" but i was throwing error like.

```
[Twig_Error_Loader]                                      
There are no registered paths for namespace "__main__".
```

before upgrading symfony2.2 it was working fine. I am not able to figure it out what is the error.

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the same issue.
What you need is explained here:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html

(Rename and Relocate your files)